# Cursors cannot yield multiple iterators mongodb error for PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple record that should return based on a query. As soon as I try to get the results I get the following error:

> Cursors cannot yield multiple iterators

The code I have is very simple:

```
    $db = \core\databaseUtilities\getDbConnection();

    $filter = [ 'email' => $email ]; 
    $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);

    $res = $db->executeQuery($db->dbName.".users", $query);
    $records = $res->toArray();
```

It fails on the last line.

I found some code examples on the web on how to query on they all pretty much looked the same. Here is the reference I used: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP's [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php) function, as suggested in [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) of the MongoCursor docs:

```
$res = $db->executeQuery($db->dbName.".users", $query);
$records = iterator_to_array($res);
```

Comment: Thank you. 
See my other answer the issue was begin caused by having a watch on $res->toArray(); issue cause while debugging and having a watch.

Comment: I had the 'Cursors cannot yield multiple iterators' exception even without a Watch set and the above answer solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it had nothing to do with the code. I am posting the answer as other may come across the same issue. It had to do with my IDE Visual Studio code. However, I assume this may not be restricted to my IDE. The problem was I had a watch on $res->toArray(); so by the time the code go to the last line in my example it was trying to iterate again. As soon as I removed the watch my issues went away no code changes necessary.